# CSS issue, need help in correcting this issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 12 squares in which number 6 has scrollable content.  but will not align up properly in the square, its all over the place.  Adjusting the screen size creates other issues.  This text shows differently in chrome and IE.  I need help in aligning the text in square 6 and keeping it there no matter the screen size or browser.

[image: test not aligning in square6]

```
        <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT='300; URL=pWebMonitor.html'> 
        <title>Web-Monitor</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="webMonitor.css">
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 


    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*Example message arrays for the two demo scrollers*/

    var pausecontent=new Array()
    pausecontent[0]='<li><span class="statusGreen">-000-</span> ....Trying to Load collected Data....</li>'
    pausecontent[1]='<li><span class="statusGreen">-000-</span> ....Trying to Load collected Data....</li>'
    pausecontent[2]='<li><span class="statusGreen">-000-</span> ....Trying to Load collected Data....</li>'

    var pausecontent2=new Array()


    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    /***********************************************
    * Pausing up-down scroller- (c) Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
    * Please keep this notice intact
    * Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more.
    ***********************************************/

    function pausescroller(content, divId, divClass, delay){
    this.content=content //message array content
    this.tickerid=divId //ID of ticker div to display information
    this.delay=delay //Delay between msg change, in miliseconds.
    this.mouseoverBol=0 //Boolean to indicate whether mouse is currently over scroller (and pause it if it is)
    this.hiddendivpointer=1 //index of message array for hidden div
    document.write('<div id="'+divId+'" class="'+divClass+'" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden"><div class="innerDiv" style="position: absolute; width: auto;" id="'+divId+'1">'+content[0]+'</div><div class="innerDiv" style="position: absolute; width: auto; visibility: hidden" id="'+divId+'2">'+content[1]+'</div></div>')
    var scrollerinstance=this
    if (window.addEventListener) //run onload in DOM2 browsers
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){scrollerinstance.initialize()}, false)
    else if (window.attachEvent) //run onload in IE5.5+
    window.attachEvent("onload", function(){scrollerinstance.initialize()})
    else if (document.getElementById) //if legacy DOM browsers, just start scroller after 0.5 sec
    setTimeout(function(){scrollerinstance.initialize()}, 500)
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // initialize()- Initialize scroller method.
    // -Get div objects, set initial positions, start up down animation
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    pausescroller.prototype.initialize=function(){
    this.tickerdiv=document.getElementById(this.tickerid)
    this.visiblediv=document.getElementById(this.tickerid+"1")
    this.hiddendiv=document.getElementById(this.tickerid+"2")
    this.visibledivtop=parseInt(pausescroller.getCSSpadding(this.tickerdiv))
    //set width of inner DIVs to outer DIV's width minus padding (padding assumed to be top padding x 2)
    this.visiblediv.style.width=this.hiddendiv.style.width=this.tickerdiv.offsetWidth-(this.visibledivtop*2)+"px"
    this.getinline(this.visiblediv, this.hiddendiv)
    this.hiddendiv.style.visibility="visible"
    var scrollerinstance=this
    document.getElementById(this.tickerid).onmouseover=function(){scrollerinstance.mouseoverBol=1}
    document.getElementById(this.tickerid).onmouseout=function(){scrollerinstance.mouseoverBol=0}
    if (window.attachEvent) //Clean up loose references in IE
    window.attachEvent("onunload", function(){scrollerinstance.tickerdiv.onmouseover=scrollerinstance.tickerdiv.onmouseout=null})
    setTimeout(function(){scrollerinstance.animateup()}, this.delay)
    }


    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // animateup()- Move the two inner divs of the scroller up and in sync
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    pausescroller.prototype.animateup=function(){
    var scrollerinstance=this
    if (parseInt(this.hiddendiv.style.top)>(this.visibledivtop+5)){
    this.visiblediv.style.top=parseInt(this.visiblediv.style.top)-5+"px"
    this.hiddendiv.style.top=parseInt(this.hiddendiv.style.top)-5+"px"
    setTimeout(function(){scrollerinstance.animateup()}, 50)
    }
    else{
    this.getinline(this.hiddendiv, this.visiblediv)
    this.swapdivs()
    setTimeout(function(){scrollerinstance.setmessage()}, this.delay)
    }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // swapdivs()- Swap between which is the visible and which is the hidden div
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    pausescroller.prototype.swapdivs=function(){
    var tempcontainer=this.visiblediv
    this.visiblediv=this.hiddendiv
    this.hiddendiv=tempcontainer
    }

    pausescroller.prototype.getinline=function(div1, div2){
    div1.style.top=this.visibledivtop+"px"
    div2.style.top=Math.max(div1.parentNode.offsetHeight, div1.offsetHeight)+"px"
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------
    // setmessage()- Populate the hidden div with the next message before it's visible
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------

    pausescroller.prototype.setmessage=function(){
    var scrollerinstance=this
    if (this.mouseoverBol==1) //if mouse is currently over scoller, do nothing (pause it)
    setTimeout(function(){scrollerinstance.setmessage()}, 100)
    else{
    var i=this.hiddendivpointer
    var ceiling=this.content.length
    this.hiddendivpointer=(i+1>ceiling-1)? 0 : i+1
    this.hiddendiv.innerHTML=this.content[this.hiddendivpointer]
    this.animateup()
    }
    }

    pausescroller.getCSSpadding=function(tickerobj){ //get CSS padding value, if any
    if (tickerobj.currentStyle)
    return tickerobj.currentStyle["paddingTop"]
    else if (window.getComputedStyle) //if DOM2
    return window.getComputedStyle(tickerobj, "").getPropertyValue("padding-top")
    else
    return 0
    }

    </script>

    </head>

    <body>                                

        <div id="squareBox">
            <p id="lastRun">Management Dashboard<span style="font-size: small;">&#169;&#8482; (v1.14)<Strong> <a href="../WebMon/WebMonitorHelp.html" target="_blank" >&#9730;</a></Strong></span><br/>

            </p>

            <div id="square1" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader"> 1 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_1">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data1"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square2" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">2 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_2">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data2"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square3" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">3 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_3">
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>

                    <tbody id="data3"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square4" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader" id="Kaiser">4 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_4">
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>UnTouched Ticket</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data4"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square5" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">5 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_5">
                    <th>Minutes</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data5"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square6" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">6 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_6">
                    <tbody id="pscroller1"></tbody> 
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square7" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">7 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_7">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data7"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square8" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">8 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_8">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data8"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square9" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">9 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_9">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data9"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square10" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">#10 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_10">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data10"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square11" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">#11 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_11">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data11"></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="square12" class="squared">
                <span class="sqHeader">#12 Monitor</span>
                <table id="tb_12">
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Longest-Queued</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <tbody id="data12"></tbody>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        //new pausescroller(name_of_message_array, CSS_ID, CSS_classname, pause_in_miliseconds)
        new pausescroller(pausecontent, "pscroller1", "someclass", 5000)
        document.write("<br />")
        //new pausescroller(pausecontent2, "pscroller2", "someclass", 2000)


    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
//CSS
        body {
        background: #d0e4fe;
        font-family: 'HP Simplified', Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    p#lastRun{
        font-family: Garamond, 'Times New Roman', Georgia, serif;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        //font-weight: bold;
        font-size:1.5em;
        text-align:center;
        background: black;
        color: white;
        }

    h1 {
        color: orange;
        text-align: center;
    }
    a {color:#7FFFD4;
    }

    #mHeader, #mHeader2{
        text-align: center;
        font: Georgia, Times, serif;
        font-size: small;
        //font-weight: bold;
    }

    /* squares configuration */

    #squareBox {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 1568px;
        height: 700px;
        //border: 2px solid #73AD21;
        //border-radius: 10px;
        //background: url(paper.gif);
        background: tan;
    }
    .squared {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        background: WhiteSmoke;
        width: 386px;
        height: 203px;
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 1px;
        outline-color: green;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        text-align: center;

    }
    #square1{
        margin-top: -18px;
    }
    #square2{
        margin-top: -18px;
    }
    #square3{
        margin-top: -18px;
    }
    #square4{
        margin-top: -18px;
    }
    #square5{

    }
    #square6{

    }
    #square7{

    }
    #square8{

    }
    #square9{

    }
    #square10{
    }
    #square11{
    }
    #square12{

    }
    .sqHeader{
        font-weight: bold;
        font-variant: small-caps;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /* Table configuration */

    th{
        font-size: small;
        font-variant:small-caps;
        background: Wheat;
    }
    table, td, th{
        margin: 1em; border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: .15em; 
        margin-top: 2px;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
    td {
        font-size:87%;

    }
    td #pscroller1 {
        //font-size: 87%;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #F8F8F8 ;
    }
    tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #99FFCC;
    }
    tbody tr:hover {
        background: #c9f;
    }

    #dataContainter, #rightNavBar, #leftNavBar{
        height: 580px;
        outline-style: solid;
        outline-width: 1px;
        outline-color: green;
    }
    #leftNavBar , #rightNavBar {
        width: 146px;
        background: light-gray;
        font-size: 74%;
    }
    #leftNavBar {
        float: left;
    }
    #rightNavBar {
        float: right;
    }
    #filterButton{
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    .statusGray {
        background: gray;
        }

    .statusRed {
        background: red;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: blink;
    }
    .statusYellow{
        background: yellow;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .statusGreen{
        background: green;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .statusBlue{
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .regionRed {
        background: #FF6600;
    }


    #displayResults  tr:hover {
        background: #FFFF00;
    }
    #customers tr.alt td {
        color: #EAF2D3;
        background: #000000;
    };
    input:focus {
        background: yellow;
    }
    button:hover {
        background: blue;
        color: white

    }
    .dEntry:focus, .qSearch:focus {
       background: #99FFFF;
    }
    .dEntry, .data {
       font-family: 'HP Simplified', Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
       //font-weight: bold;
       //font-size: 80%;
       //color: blue;
    }
    /*****************************************************
     * generic styling for ALS elements: outer container
     ******************************************************/

    /*Example CSS for the two demo scrollers*/

    div#pscroller1 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 340px;
        height: 160px;
        bottom: 405px;
        padding: 5px;
        left: 465px;
        //border: 1px solid black;
    }


    #pscroller2{
    width: 700px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 3px;

    }

    #pscroller1 li, #pscroller1 a{
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-size: 89%; 
        font-variant:small-caps; 
        font-weight: bold;
        color: black;
    }


    .someclass{ //class to apply to your scroller(s) if desired
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed by "scrollable content" you mean automatically moving across the screen. What about using a marquee library?

Here's a fiddle I put together on your grid: https://jsfiddle.net/7gz5x1mk/1/
using the jquery marquee plugin http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples

HTML

```
 <div id="square6" class="squared" style="border: 1px solid red;">
        <span class="sqHeader">6 Monitor</span>
         <div class="marquee">jQuery marquee is the best <b>marquee</b> plugin in the world</div>
    </div>
```

HTML for vertical scrolling

```
    <div class="marquee ver" data-direction='up' data-duration='1000' data-pauseOnHover="true">
      jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world. jQuery marquee is the best marquee plugin in the world <b>end</b>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$('.marquee').marquee();
```

CSS

```
.marquee {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, i need the content to scroll up vertical

Comment: About halfway down the example link I provided above there is a section called "Direction". See the fiddle update at https://jsfiddle.net/7gz5x1mk/2/

Comment: Again thanks for your effort, I did finally see the "direction:" option.  I did notice it shifted squares 8-12 out of alignment. Any ideas?  wish i could figure this all out.

Comment: Again Thank you for all your help everything worked out fine and i am now using it.